# Linq Query Condition for multiple row

Tags: database, linq, linq-to-entities

I tried to solve one query from last 2 days but didn't.
It looks easy to understand but can't made.

There are two column in Table for example:

```
ResourceId  ||   MappingId

      1            2
      1            3
      2            2
      2            4
      3            2
      3            4
      4            2
      4            5
      5            2
      5            4
```

This is one table which have two fields ResourceId and MappingId.
Now I want resourceId which have Mappingid {2,4}

Means answer must be ResourceId {2,3,5}

How can I get this answer in Linq Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Contains` of collection. This method can be translated by Entity Framework into SQL IN operator:

```
int[] mappingIds = { 2, 4 };
var resources = from t in table
                where mappingIds.Contains(t.MappingId)
                select t.ResourceId;
```

Lambda syntax:

```
var  resources = table.Where(t => mappingIds.Contains(t.MappingId))
                      .Select(t => t.ResourceId);
```

Generated SQL will look like:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[ResourceId]
FROM [dbo].[TableName] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[MappingId] IN (2,4)
```

---

UPDATE: If you want to get resources which have ALL provided mapping ids, then

```
var resources = from t in table
                group t by t.ResourceId into g
                where mappingIds.All(id => g.Any(t => t.Id == id))
                select g.Key;
```

Entity Framework is able to translate this query into SQL, but it will not be that beautiful as query above.

Comment: Thanks Sergey.. but if i use Contains than get resource either mapping id have 2 or its id 4.. not both...

Comment: @user3410950 it will give you all rows which have any of provided mapping ids

Comment: but i want resourceid which must have both MappingId {2,4}.. In your case ResourceId comes either MappingId have 2 or it 4 means Or condition

Answer (score 1):

```
IQueryable<int> resourceIds = table
     // groups items by ResourceId
     .GroupBy(item => item.ResourceId)
     // consider only group where: an item has 2 as MappingId value
     .Where(group => group.Select(item => item.MappingId).Contains(2))
     // AND where: an item has 4 as MappingId value
     .Where(group => group.Select(item => item.MappingId).Contains(4))
     // select Key (= ResourceId) of filtered groups
     .Select(group => group.Key);
```